# Android-Studio: Layout for wide screen in a portrait mode

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, layout, landscape-portrait

I have an application that should work in a portrait mode only.
it works great using just (Layout) resources.
Now I face a problem with some device,

- The device has only Portrait mode, no orientation, it is ok for me.
- The screen height is smaller than its width, and remember this is not landscape mode.

  ```
   __________
  | portrait |
  |__________|
  ```
- If I used Layout-land, it will not work, and the device pick the normal layout resource.

I tried `layout-sw`, `layout-w`, `layout-h`, without solution.

I want the normal devices to use "layout" and the devices which has height smaller than the width use another layout.

And remember please, this is not a landscape.

Thanks in advance.

===========================================================

### Update

Is there any way to use Layout-11x00, where 11 is the width, and the 00 is the height? I tried it and it worked, but the problem is it worked for all devices, not the wide devices only. I tried Layout-774x480 as w=774 and h=480. but it worked also with my Samsung mobile, I do not want this.
Why when I set the layout to "Layout-774x480" it targeted my samsung? while my samsung width is not > height?! I mean what is the different between "Layout-774x480" and "Layout-480x774"?

Comment: Thanks Reaz for the edit.

Comment: You are most welcome. :)

Comment: Anyone can help, please? how can I solve this problem?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can set a qualifier along with the layout folder name to get your layout picked from that specific folder when you are running your application in a device. [Here is the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#alternative-layouts) where I recommend you to take a look.

In your case you just have to create a layout directory named `res/layout-w600dp/main_activity.xml` which indicates if the device screen is 600dp wide and bigger, the layout will be picked from this folder.

I checked that you have tried already with `layout-w`, `layout-h` and `layout-sw` settings. However, I think you are missing the expected width of the device screen which should be picked.

Hope that helps!

**Update**

If you are willing to set different layout based on the decision that the height is less than the width, then you might just consider checking the screen height and width before setting the content view of the activity.

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

if(height > width) setContentView(R.layout.main_activity.xml);
else setContentView(R.layout.main_activity_wide.xml);
```

Comment: Thanks. but I do not mean exact wide. I have some devices which have its width > it height in the portrait mode (it is not landscape). how to create Layout for these devices besides the normal ones.

Comment: Thanks, but there is no way to do this without hardcoded it? Also, if I checked the width and height, and check if w>h, wont it give me true if the device is in the landscape mode? I mean, I want to let it work with the normal devices, and also the wide devices. Also, if I hardcoded it, then I have to handel all the drawable in code by myself.

Comment: You can handle the landscape mode easily by overriding the function `onConfigurationChanges`. However, the dynamic mode is not suitable for your situation which I suggested before already.

Comment: I mean, I have one device in portrait mode and its w>h. another device in landscape mode and its w>h. I do not let my application to work in landscape mode, but in these two cases, the (if w > h ) will = true.

Comment: can I use Layout-11x00, where 11 is the width, and the 00 is the height? I tried it and it worked, but the problem is it worked for all devices, not the wide devices only. I tried Layout-774x480 as w=774 and h=480. but it worked also with my Samsung mobile, I do not want this.

Comment: Then I think setting the content programatically is the only solution for you. However, writing the same code again and again, I think you might consider having a helper class, so that you just keep the layout choosing code in that file and do not make the other classes dirty.

Comment: Anyone can help, please? how can I solve this problem?

Regards